# How do I get the URLs of files attached to items in my list?

Tags: 2013, list, client-object-model

I'm using the CSOM to get my SharePoint list. I need to loop through it and get the URLs for the files attached to each item in the list.

C#:

```
SPContext spctx = new SPContext("news");

List news = spctx.getList("News");

ListItemCollection lc = spctx.getListItems(news);

for (int i = 0; i < lc.Count; i++)
{
    AttachmentCollection attachments = lc[i].AttachmentFiles;
    for (int j = 0; j < attachments.Count; j++)
    {
        var test = attachments[j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the pseudo code you can use

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
{
    Folder folder = oWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(oSite.Url + "/Lists/"+listName+/Attachments/" + listItem["ID"]);
    clientContext.Load(folder);

    try
    {
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
    catch (ServerException ex)
    {

    }
    FileCollection attachments = folder.Files;
    clientContext.Load(attachments);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File oFile in folder.Files)
    {
        //oFile.ServerRelativeUrl - Contains the attachment URL
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question. To clarify I'm stuck trying to get the URLs from the AttachmentCollection.

Answer (score 2):

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve all attachments for list items using CSOM:

```
//Retrieve list items attachments 
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery()); 
ctx.Load(items, icol => icol.Include(i => i["Title"], i => i.AttachmentFiles));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

//Print attachment Urls for list items
foreach (var item in items)
{
     if (item.AttachmentFiles.Count > 0)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} attachments:", item["Title"]);
        foreach (var attachment in item.AttachmentFiles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(attachment.ServerRelativeUrl);
        }
     }
     else
     {
          Console.WriteLine("For {0} list item no attachments were found", item["Title"]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I actually wrote this in my code but without the title inclusion. Calling ctx.ExecuteQuery() gives me a "Value does not fall within expected range" error. What could that mean? None of the list items have attachments yet.

Comment: @Dinerdo, do you mind to post a separate question with your example, i would be glad to take a look

Comment: I posted the question. I believe I figured out a way to make it work, but my question now is about choosing the best efficiency: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/161159/query-list-for-all-list-items-and-their-attachments-using-csom