# Query list for all list items and their attachments using CSOM

Tags: development, csom, attachments

I've used the following code to retrieve the list items on my SP site. The following code will return "Value does not fall within the expected range" if I try to get the AttachmentFiles:

```
            bool success = true;
            const int max = 20;  //when i % 25 == 0 , upload all at once 
            int counter = 1;

            //grab all items in list and include AttachmentFiles in load
            List tracker = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tracker");
            string[] viewFields = { "Title" "ThisTime", "Proprietary" };
            ListItemCollection listItems = tracker.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(5000, viewFields));
            ctx.Load(listItems, _coll => _coll.Include(itm => itm.AttachmentFiles));

            try
            {
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogError.Log("Failed to access list items", ex.Message, ctx);
                return false;
            }
```

Unless I add "Attachments" as one of the view fields, this returns the range error. When I add "Attachments" as one of the view fields and leave the rest of the code as-is, this does remove the error and give me the attachment collection. However, none of the other fields are retrieved. I'm guessing that I can get around this by adding "item["Title"]" and so on inside the Include method. But is this really the most efficient method? Would I not be better off just excluding the ViewFields parameter? I attempted to avoid using the Include altogether, but the attachment collection is not initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error since attachments are not included via query (view fields). `Attachments` column is not the same as `AttachmentFiles` property, first one only returns status whether attachments are included or not, while the second returns attachments info.

Since your goal is to retrieve a specific set of fields plus attachments included, you could consider the following approach:

```
List tracker = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tracker"); 
ListItemCollection listItems = tracker.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(5000));
ctx.Load(listItems, icol => icol.Include(i => i.AttachmentFiles, i => i["Title"], i => i["ThisTime"], i => i["Proprietary"]));

try
{
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
      LogError.Log("Failed to access list items", ex.Message, ctx);
 }
```

Comment: I understand that Attachments aren't included in the view fields. I was saying that I get the error unless I include Attachments in the view fields because I actually _don't_ get that error when I add it there. I was wondering if there was a relationship that could be taken advantage of here since this removes the "range" error.
/n

But.. the answer I was looking for was more about if I should exclude the viewfields at all and just spell them out in the Include. From your answer, I'm thinking that's a yes. Thanks :)